# ASP.NET MVC - Cannot redirect to Create action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've had a look around at the other questions related to redirecting to views, and none seem to fix my issue. I have a intermediary step to get to my Create action, and I cannot seem to redirect from that step's view to the Create view. An approximation of my actual code is:

```
public ActionResult SelectDependancy()
{
    ViewBag.ProductID = new SelectList(db.Products, "ID", "Name");
    ViewBag.ComponentID = new SelectList(db.Components, "ID", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

The view for this action has a POST method that results in a call to `SelectDependancy(string, string)`.

This POST is a standard POST and not an js AJAX POST

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void SelectDependancy(string ProductID, string ComponentID)
{
    FilteredCreate(ProductID, ComponentID);
}

private ActionResult FilteredCreate(string ProductID, string ComponentID)
{
    //Filter values based on ProductID + ComponentID

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

The `return RedirectToAction("Create");` doesn't seem to work. I have also tried changing it to `return View("Create")` (changing the return type of the method as well)

Comment: What about redirecting to the Create action "doesn't seem to work"?  How specifically is it failing?  In your last code snippet the `SelectDependancy` action doesn't return *anything*, so it's not really clear to me what you're doing.

Comment: Is there a reason for having FilteredCreate?

Comment: change `public void SelectDependancy` to `public ActionResult SelectDependancy`. And inside the method `return FilteredCreate(ProductID, ComponentID);`

Comment: @David The create view is not displayed, and the URL does not update (although I'm not sure if it should), I was hoping that the view would be redirected as although there is no return on `SelectDependancy` there is for `FilteredCreate`

Comment: @S.Akbari The `SelectDependancy` method is definitely called, it gets all the way to `FilteredCreate`

Comment: @JLewis: In that case the answer posted below is what you want.  An action has to return a redirect in order for a redirect to happen.  Or, more generally, an action has to return *something* in order for there to be any result at all.

Comment: @BadDub I'm using to narrow down the selection in dropdowns, selecting only subcomponents of a particular product, rather than just from all subcomponents

Comment: Could you not just do that all in one actionresult?

Comment: @adiga You were right, thanks a lot

Comment: @BadDub Maybe, but I'm not sure how to dynamically update the "filtered" dropdown lists once a selection had been made. That might well be my next question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return `ActionResult` from `SelectDependancy` in order to redirect.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SelectDependancy(string ProductID, string ComponentID)
{
    return FilteredCreate(ProductID, ComponentID);
}
```